# My prepareForSegue() Method is not working

Tags: swift, xcode, prepare

So I'm trying to move an image from the first page to the second page. But my prepare() method is not working and I do not know why.. 
I tried to put override before the prepare function but it says the function is not overriding anything so I could not.

```
import UIKit

class BeginningPage: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    ImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK: Action

@IBAction func PressImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func prepare(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController {
        destination.text = "123"
        destination.image = ImageView.image
        destination.LayerImage.image = ImageView.image
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you should connect your segue from the VC and give it a identifier..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your naming is wrong. Check the right version [in docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare). Method definition should look like this:

**Swift 3:**

`override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

**Swift 2:**

`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`